# Wordpress new folder and file permissions are not correct

Tags: wordpress, permissions, ftp, user-roles

I have read through a bunch of sites, but I could only find the right permission to set to existing files and folders, but I could not find anything related to the new files and folders to be created.

Whenever I create a new file or folder they will be created with permissions `660` and `770`, so some of the contents are not accessible. For example if I install a plugin, it will be installed with `770` and `660` permissions, so I get a `403` error through the javascript console for all assets of the plugin.

Is there a way/plugin, to adjust persmissions to the files and folders to be created in the future, not just the existing ones?

> Please note:
>
> - I don't have SSH access (or any access, but FTP) to the hosting
>   server.
> - Disabling all themes & plugins doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these two lines to the `wp-config.php` file solved the problem:

```
define('FS_CHMOD_FILE', 0644);
define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0755);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filezilla, it will take some time but works fine,

http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/navigation-customization/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-your-ftp-site/

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm okay with the existing ones, I can change them. The problem is with the freshly created folders and files